# Why does the SetDIBitsToDevice not working?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I am trying to simulate a horizontal and vertical scroll of a DI bitmap that is larger than the page in the main dialog. The problem is that the contents in the page does not change when scrolling.

The location of the page in the main dialog is at point (8, 100) and its size is (400, 500). The DI bitmap, when zoomed in, is 150 percentage the size of the page.

Here is the code that scrolls the page:

```
//The function that scrolls the page
//horizontally and vertically.
TRESULT ScrollPage(_IN HWND inobj1, \
                   _IN void *inobj2, \
                   _IN int inn1, \
                   _IN int inn2, \
                   _IN int inn3, \
                   _IN int inn4, \
                   _IN int inn5, \
                   _IN int inn6, \
                   _IN int inn7){

 //Variable declarations
 BITMAPINFO *tmpbmpinfo = 0;
 BITMAPINFOHEADER *tmpbmphdr = 0;
 void *tmpbits = 0;
 HWND tmphndwindow = 0;
 HDC tmphdc;
 int tmpn = 0;
 int tmpn2 = 0;
 int tmpn3 = 0;
 int tmpn4 = 0;
 int tmpn5 = 0;
 int tmpn6 = 0;
 int tmpn7 = 0;
 int tmpn8 = 0;
 int ret = 0;
 int ret2 = 0;

 //Argument checks
 if(inobj1 == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 } //EndIf
 if(inobj2 == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 } //EndIf

 //Initializations
 tmphndwindow = inobj1;
 tmpbits = inobj2;  //A DI Bitmap.
 tmpn = inn1;       //x-coordinate of the page.
 tmpn2 = inn2;      //y-coordinate of the page.
 tmpn3 = inn3;      //Width, in pixels, of the page.
 tmpn4 = inn4;      //Height, in pixels, of the page.
 tmpn5 = inn5;      //Percentage of image size to page size.
 tmpn6 = inn6;      //Horizontal scroll.
 tmpn7 = inn7;      //Vertical scroll.

 //Main logic

 //Start to scroll the page.

 //Get a handle to a device context.
 tmphdc = GetDC(tmphndwindow);

 //Calculate the height of the image
 //using the percentage.
 tmpn8 = ((tmpn4 * tmpn5) / 100);

 //Allocate memory to tmpbmpinfo.
 tmpbmpinfo = (BITMAPINFO*)calloc(1, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

 //Set the tmpbmphdr variable.
 tmpbmphdr = &(tmpbmpinfo->bmiHeader);

 //Set the members of the bitmap info
 //header.
 tmpbmphdr->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
 tmpbmphdr->biWidth = (tmpn + tmpn3);
 tmpbmphdr->biHeight = (tmpn2 + tmpn8);
 tmpbmphdr->biPlanes = 1;
 tmpbmphdr->biBitCount = 32;
 tmpbmphdr->biCompression = BI_RGB;
 tmpbmphdr->biSizeImage = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biClrUsed = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biClrImportant = 0;

 //Calculate the width of the image
 //using the percentage.
 tmpn3 = ((tmpn3 * tmpn5) / 100);

 //Set the bits to the device context
 //and to the display device.
 SetDIBitsToDevice(tmphdc, \
                   tmpn, \
                   tmpn2, \
                   tmpn3, \
                   (tmpn4 - tmpn7), \
                   (tmpn + tmpn6), \
                   0, \
                   0, \
                   tmpn8, \
                   tmpbits, \
                   tmpbmpinfo, \
                   DIB_RGB_COLORS);
     
 //Release the device context.
 ReleaseDC(tmphndwindow, \
           tmphdc);

 //Free variables
 free(tmpbmpinfo);

 //Returns
 return TSUCCESS;

} //End ScrollPage
```

Here is the code that handles the WM_HSCROLL message. All tmpbits are static pointers:

```
 //Handle the WM_HSCROLL message.
 if(tmpmsg == WM_HSCROLL){

  //Get the type of horizontal scroll.
  tmpn = (tmpwparam & 0xFFFF);

  //Check if the user scrolled one unit
  //to the right.
  if(tmpn == SB_LINERIGHT){

   //Add one to the tmphscroll variable.
   tmphscroll = (tmphscroll + 1);

  } //EndIf

  //Check if the user scrolled one unit
  //to the left.
  if(tmpn == SB_LINELEFT){

   //Subtract one from the tmphscroll
   //variable.
   tmphscroll = (tmphscroll - 1);

  } //EndIf

  //Check if the user is scrolling either
  //to the right or to the left.
  if(tmpn == SB_THUMBTRACK){

   //Set the tmphscroll variable.
   tmphscroll = (tmpwparam >> 16);

  } //EndIf

  //Search for the horizontal scroll
  //control.
  tmphndwindow2 = GetDlgItem(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
                 6);

  //Set some members of the tmpscrollinfo
  //object.
  tmpscrollinfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
  tmpscrollinfo.fMask = SIF_POS;
  tmpscrollinfo.nPos = tmphscroll;

  //Set the position of the scroll box.
  SetScrollInfo(tmphndwindow2, \
                SB_CTL, \
                &tmpscrollinfo, \
                TRUE);

  //Check if the user pressed the zoom
  //button.
  if(tmpn3 == 1){

   //Set tmpbits3 to tmpbits2.
   tmpbits3 = tmpbits2;

   //Set tmpn to 150.
   tmpn = 150;

   //Set tmpn3 to 2.
   tmpn3 = 2;

  }else{

   //Check if tmpn3 is equal to 0.
   if(tmpn3 == 0){

    //Check if tmpbits is NULL.
    if(tmpbits == NULL){

     //Get the DI bitmap of the page's
     //client area. This bitmap starts
     //at the bottom-left corner of the
     //page and ends at the top-right
     //corner of the main dialog.
     GetDIBPage(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
                &tmpbits);

    } //EndIf

    //Set tmpbits3 to tmpbits.
    tmpbits3 = tmpbits;

    //Set tmpn to 100.
    tmpn = 100;

   } //EndIf
  } //EndIf

  //Scroll the page's client area
  //horizontally.
  ScrollPage(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
             tmpbits3, \
             8, \
             100, \
             400, \
             500, \
             tmpn, \
             tmphscroll, \
             tmpvscroll);

  //Returns
  return FALSE;

 } //End WM_HSCROLL
```

Here is the code that sets tmpbits2. This code is placed in the handler of the WM_PAINT message:

```
  //Check if the zoom button was pressed.
  if(tmpn3 == 1){

   //Get a device context for the window.
   tmphdc2 = GetDC(GLB_HWndMainDialog);

   //Get a memory device context.
   tmphdc3 = CreateCompatibleDC(tmphdc2);

   //Set the stretch Blt mode.
   SetStretchBltMode(tmphdc2, \
                     BLACKONWHITE);

   //Set the stretch Blt mode.
   SetStretchBltMode(tmphdc3, \
                     BLACKONWHITE);

   //Check if tmpbits is not NULL.
   if(tmpbits != NULL){

    //Free tmpbits.
    free(tmpbits);

   } //EndIf

   //Get the DI bitmap of the page's
   //client area. This bitmap starts
   //at the bottom-left corner of the
   //page and ends at the top-right
   //corner of the main dialog.
   GetDIBPage(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
              &tmpbits);
 
   //Check if tmpbits2 is NULL.
   if(tmpbits2 == NULL){

    //Allocate memory to tmpbits2.
    tmpbits2 = (void*)calloc((4 * 620 * 900), sizeof(char));

   } //EndIf

   //Set the DI Bits to tmphdc3. tmphdc3
   //is a memory device context that will
   //be used in situations where the str-
   //etched page is bigger that the page
   //dimensions.

   //Allocate memory to tmpbmpinfo.
   tmpbmpinfo = (BITMAPINFO*)calloc(1, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

   //Set the tmpbmphdr variable.
   tmpbmphdr = &(tmpbmpinfo->bmiHeader);

   //Set the members of the bitmap info
   //header
   tmpbmphdr->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
   tmpbmphdr->biWidth = 408;
   tmpbmphdr->biHeight = 600;
   tmpbmphdr->biPlanes = 1;
   tmpbmphdr->biBitCount = 32;
   tmpbmphdr->biCompression = BI_RGB;
   tmpbmphdr->biSizeImage = 0;
   tmpbmphdr->biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
   tmpbmphdr->biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
   tmpbmphdr->biClrUsed = 0;
   tmpbmphdr->biClrImportant = 0;

   //Create a bitmap.
   tmphbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(tmphdc2, \
                                       608, \
                                       850);

   //Select the bitmap into the memory
   //device context.
   SelectObject(tmphdc3, tmphbitmap);

   //Zoom and copy the pixels to the 
   //memory DC.
   StretchDIBits(tmphdc3, \
                 8, \
                 100, \
                 600, \
                 750, \
                 8, \
                 100, \
                 400, \
                 500, \
                 tmpbits, \
                 tmpbmpinfo, \
                 DIB_RGB_COLORS, \
                 SRCCOPY);

   //Update some members of the bitmap
   //info object.
   tmpbmphdr->biWidth = 608;
   tmpbmphdr->biHeight = 850;

   //Copy the bits from the bitmap into
   //tmpbits2. This does not include the
   //bitmap header.
   GetDIBits(tmphdc3, \
             tmphbitmap, \
             0, \
             850, \
             tmpbits2, \
             tmpbmpinfo, \
             DIB_RGB_COLORS);

   //Set tmphscroll to zero.
   tmphscroll = 0;

   //Search for the horizontal scroll
   //control.
   tmphndwindow2 = GetDlgItem(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
                              6);

   //Set some members of the tmpscrollinfo
   //object.
   tmpscrollinfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
   tmpscrollinfo.fMask = SIF_POS;
   tmpscrollinfo.nPos = tmphscroll;

   //Set the position of the scroll box.
   SetScrollInfo(tmphndwindow2, \
                 SB_CTL, \
                 &tmpscrollinfo, \
                 TRUE);

   //Set tmpvscroll to zero.
   tmpvscroll = 0;

   //Search for the vertical scroll
   //control.
   tmphndwindow2 = GetDlgItem(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
                              5);

   //Set some members of the tmpscrollinfo
   //object.
   tmpscrollinfo.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
   tmpscrollinfo.fMask = SIF_POS;
   tmpscrollinfo.nPos = tmpvscroll;

   //Set the position of the scroll box.
   SetScrollInfo(tmphndwindow2, \
                 SB_CTL, \
                 &tmpscrollinfo, \
                 TRUE);

   //Scroll the page's client area.
   ScrollPage(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
              tmpbits2, \
              8, \
              100, \
              400, \
              500, \
              150, \
              tmphscroll, \
              tmpvscroll);

   //Release the device context.
   ReleaseDC(GLB_HWndMainDialog, \
             tmphdc2);

   //Free variables
   DeleteObject(tmphbitmap);
   DeleteDC(tmphdc3);
   free(tmpbmpinfo);
 
  } //EndIf
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Aside - function argument lists do not require  the line continuation character ( \ ) to allow putting argument on next line.  A simple comma followed by a newline between arguments suffices.

Comment: Its good that you've shown code, but this code does not show how your are calling these routines.  Please edit post to include a [mcve], focusing on providing the minimum code necessary to execute and illustrate the problem.)

Comment: The message handlers are in the window procedure for the main dialog. So the system handles that call. As for the ScrollPage function, it is called in the handler to WM_PAINT and WM_HSCROLL as shown in the code.

Comment: Again, without [mcve] it is difficult to track source of problem.  Best I can do is wonder about how `tmpbit` variations in your code are being passed around.  eg. code does not check for success on some of the calls to `calloc`. and overwriting some variations wiith others (eg: `tmpbits = inobj2`, `tmpbits3 = tmpbits2`, `tmpbits2 = (void*)calloc`, ...) ,  Without more specificity, not sure how much help there can be.

Comment: I did not make the code strong because I'm still performing the Feasibility Study as part of the project development. This stage involves verifying whether the project can be done based on available resources and the current skills of the project team. I will attempt to make a minimal reproducible example and post it later.

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow programmers;

I have finally achieved the results I was looking for. I had to define a new function that zooms in the page called GetDIBPageZ. That function gets the DI Bitmap of the zoomed in page. Then in the ScrollPage function, I copied the areas in that DI Bitmap based on the vertical and horizontal scroll numbers. For example, if the user scrolled towards the right x positions, then the ScrollPage function will copy the specified DI Bitmap starting x positions to the right. The code for those two functions is below.

```
//The function that gets the DIB
//from a zoomed in page.
TRESULT GetDIBPageZ(_IN HWND inobj,
                    _INOUT void **outobj){

 //Variable declarations
 BITMAPINFO *tmpbmpinfo = 0;
 BITMAPINFOHEADER *tmpbmphdr = 0;
 void *tmpbits = 0;
 char *tmpstr = 0;
 HWND tmphndwindow = 0;
 HBITMAP tmphbitmap = 0;
 HDC tmphdc = 0;
 HDC tmphdc2 = 0;
 int ret = 0;
 int ret2 = 0;

 //Argument checks
 if(outobj == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 } //EndIf

 //Initializations
 tmphndwindow = inobj;

 //Main logic

 //Start to get the DIB.
 
 //Allocate memory to tmpstr.
 tmpstr = (char*)calloc(513, sizeof(char));

 //Get a device context for the window.
 tmphdc = GetDC(tmphndwindow);

 //Get a memory device context.
 tmphdc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(tmphdc);

 //Set the stretch Blt mode.
 SetStretchBltMode(tmphdc2,
                   BLACKONWHITE);

 //Allocate memory to tmpbits.
 tmpbits = (void*)calloc((4 * 620 * 900), sizeof(char));
 if(tmpbits == NULL){

  //Show error to user.
  MessageBox(NULL, 
             "Failed to initialize tmpbits.", 
             "Error", 
             MB_OK);
  
  //Free variables.
  free(tmpstr);

  //Returns
  return TCREATEFAILED;
 } //EndIf

 //Set the DI Bits to tmphdc3. tmphdc3
 //is a memory device context that will
 //be used in situations where the str-
 //etched page is bigger that the page
 //dimensions.

 //Create a bitmap.
 tmphbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(tmphdc, 
                                     608, 
                                     850);
 if(tmphbitmap == NULL){

  //Build error string.
  sprintf(tmpstr, 
"CreateCompatibleBitmap failed.\n%d",
GetLastError());
 
  //Show error to user.
  MessageBox(NULL, 
             tmpstr, 
             "Error", 
             MB_OK);
  
  //Free variables.
  free(tmpstr);

  //Returns
  return TCREATEFAILED;
 } //EndIf

 //Select the bitmap into the memory
 //device context.
 SelectObject(tmphdc2, tmphbitmap);

 //Zoom in the page and copy the pixels
 //to the tmphdc3 device context.
 ret = StretchBlt(tmphdc2, 
                  8, 
                  100, 
                  600, 
                  750, 
                  tmphdc, 
                  8, 
                  100, 
                  400, 
                  500, 
                  SRCCOPY);
 if(ret == 0){

  //Build error string.
  sprintf(tmpstr, 
"StretchBlt failed.\n%d", 
GetLastError());
 
  //Show error to user.
  MessageBox(NULL, 
             tmpstr, 
             "Error", 
             MB_OK);
  
  //Free variables.
  free(tmpstr);

  //Returns
  return TFAILED;
 } //EndIf

 //Allocate memory to tmpbmpinfo.
 tmpbmpinfo = (BITMAPINFO*)calloc(1, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

 //Set the tmpbmphdr variable.
 tmpbmphdr = &(tmpbmpinfo->bmiHeader);

 //Set the members of the bitmap info
 //header.
 tmpbmphdr->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
 tmpbmphdr->biWidth = 608;
 tmpbmphdr->biHeight = 850;
 tmpbmphdr->biPlanes = 1;
 tmpbmphdr->biBitCount = 32;
 tmpbmphdr->biCompression = BI_RGB;
 tmpbmphdr->biSizeImage = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biClrUsed = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biClrImportant = 0;

 //Copy the bits from the bitmap into
 //tmpbits. This does not include the
 //bitmap header.
 ret = GetDIBits(tmphdc2, 
                 tmphbitmap, 
                 0, 
                 850, 
                 tmpbits, 
                 tmpbmpinfo, 
                 DIB_RGB_COLORS);
 if(ret == 0){

  //Build error string.
  sprintf(tmpstr, 
"GetDIBits failed.\n%d", 
GetLastError());
 
  //Show error to user.
  MessageBox(NULL, 
             tmpstr, 
             "Error", 
             MB_OK);
  
  //Free variables.
  free(tmpstr);

  //Returns
  return TFAILED;
 } //EndIf

 //Release the device context.
 ReleaseDC(tmphndwindow, 
           tmphdc);

 //Free variables
 DeleteObject(tmphbitmap);
 DeleteDC(tmphdc2);
 free(tmpbmpinfo);
 free(tmpstr);

 //Returns
 *outobj = tmpbits;
 return TSUCCESS;

} //End GetDIBPageZ
```

```
//The function that scrolls the page
//horizontally and vertically.
TRESULT ScrollPage(_IN HWND inobj1, \
                   _IN void *inobj2, \
                   _IN int inn1, \
                   _IN int inn2, \
                   _IN int inn3, \
                   _IN int inn4, \
                   _IN int inn5, \
                   _IN int inn6, \
                   _IN int inn7){

 //Variable declarations
 BITMAPINFO *tmpbmpinfo = 0;
 BITMAPINFOHEADER *tmpbmphdr = 0;
 void *tmpbits = 0;
 void *tmpbits2 = 0;
 HWND tmphndwindow = 0;
 HDC tmphdc = 0;
 int tmpn = 0;
 int tmpn2 = 0;
 int tmpn3 = 0;
 int tmpn4 = 0;
 int tmpn5 = 0;
 int tmpn6 = 0;
 int tmpn7 = 0;
 int tmpn8 = 0;
 int tmpn9 = 0;
 int tmpn10 = 0;
 int tmpn11 = 0;
 int tmpn12 = 0;
 int tmpn13 = 0;
 int tmpn14 = 0;
 int tmpn15 = 0;
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 int ret = 0;
 int ret2 = 0;

 //Argument checks
 if(inobj2 == NULL){
  return TPTRISNULL;
 } //EndIf
 if(inn5 < 100){
  return TPARAMETERINVALID;
 } //EndIf

 //Initializations
 tmphndwindow = inobj1;
 tmpbits = inobj2;  //A DI Bitmap.
 tmpn = inn1;       //x-coordinate of the page.
 tmpn2 = inn2;      //y-coordinate of the page.
 tmpn3 = inn3;      //Width, in pixels, of the page.
 tmpn4 = inn4;      //Height, in pixels, of the page.
 tmpn5 = inn5;      //Percentage of image size to page size.
 tmpn6 = inn6;      //Horizontal scroll.
 tmpn7 = inn7;      //Vertical scroll.

 //Main logic

 //Start to scroll the page.

 //Get a handle to a device context.
 tmphdc = GetDC(tmphndwindow);

 //Allocate memory to tmpbits2.
 tmpbits2 = calloc((4 * (tmpn + tmpn3) * \
                   (tmpn2 + tmpn4)),
                   sizeof(char));

 //Calculate the width of the image
 //using the percentage.
 tmpn8 = ((tmpn3 * tmpn5) / 100);

 //Calculate the height of the image
 //using the percentage.
 tmpn9 = ((tmpn4 * tmpn5) / 100);

 //Allocate memory to tmpbmpinfo.
 tmpbmpinfo = (BITMAPINFO*)calloc(1, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

 //Set the tmpbmphdr variable.
 tmpbmphdr = &(tmpbmpinfo->bmiHeader);

 //Set the members of the bitmap info
 //header.
 tmpbmphdr->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
 tmpbmphdr->biWidth = tmpn3;
 tmpbmphdr->biHeight = tmpn4;
 tmpbmphdr->biPlanes = 1;
 tmpbmphdr->biBitCount = 32;
 tmpbmphdr->biCompression = BI_RGB;
 tmpbmphdr->biSizeImage = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biClrUsed = 0;
 tmpbmphdr->biClrImportant = 0;

 //Calculate the starting x coordinate
 //based on the percentage.
 if(tmpn5 == 100){
  tmpn14 = 0;
  tmpn15 = tmpn6;
 }else{
  tmpn14 = tmpn6;
  tmpn15 = 0;
 }

 //Calculate the starting y coordinate
 //based on the percentage.
 if(tmpn5 == 100){
  tmpn13 = 0;
 }else{
  tmpn13 = abs(((tmpn9 - tmpn4) - tmpn7));
 }

 //Start a for loop. This loop iterates
 //for each row starting at the lower
 //left corner of the bitmap.
 for(i = tmpn13; i < (tmpn9 - tmpn7); i++){

  //Get the current row in tmpbits.
  tmpn10 = (i * (tmpn + tmpn8));

  //Start another for loop. This row
  //iterates for each column, starting
  //from the lower left corner of the
  //bitmap.
  for(j = 0; j < tmpn3; j++){

   //Calculate the current offset
   //into tmpbits.
   tmpn11 = (tmpn10 + tmpn14 + j);

   //Set the pixel from tmpbits to
   //tmpbits2.
   ((int*)tmpbits2)[tmpn12] = ((int*)tmpbits)[tmpn11];

   //Add one to tmpn12.
   tmpn12 = (tmpn12 + 1);

  } //End for loop
 } //End for loop

 //Set the bits to the device context
 //and to the display device.
 SetDIBitsToDevice(tmphdc, 
                   tmpn, 
                   tmpn2, 
                   tmpn3, 
                   (tmpn4 - tmpn7), 
                   (tmpn + tmpn15),
                   0, 
                   0, 
                   (tmpn4 - tmpn7), 
                   tmpbits2, 
                   tmpbmpinfo, 
                   DIB_RGB_COLORS);
     
 //Release the device context.
 ReleaseDC(tmphndwindow, 
           tmphdc);

 //Free variables
 free(tmpbmpinfo);
 free(tmpbits2);

 //Returns
 return TSUCCESS;

} //End ScrollPage
```